# spinner width does not matches with spinner item width

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

When I use specific width like `400dp` for the DropDown item's width and `spinner` width it matches properly.

But When I am using `match_parent` for the `spinner` and `custom_spinner_item` width it does not match? Image may give an idea[image]
What is wrong with my code? I want the same width using `match_parent`?

This is my custom `custom_spinner_item`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="400dp"            // width
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:text="wallets"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:textColor="#282727"/>
    <View
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="#8e8c8c"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

My Fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/appbackground"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp">   

    // some code

   <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dropDownLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/zxing_roundedbgwhite"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_width="400dp"        // width
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:dropDownWidth="400dp"       // width
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
    </LinearLayout>

    // some code

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: does it make any sense? still tried. it's not working.

Comment: Put your main layout and also the class that reads your fragment.

Comment: I can't see the problem in the picture you attached, it seems to have the same width

Comment: @batsheva I want to make width of view with arrow and dropdown view same

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The best way will be hiding down arrow of `Spinner` by giving

```
android:background="@null"
```

to `Spinner`

So that item will take whole space of `Spinner`

Then put down arrow in a `ImageView` and align to right of `Spinner`

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:dropDownWidth="match_parent"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/spinner1" 
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_down"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/spinner1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/spinner1"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: where should I put ImageView for arrow?