# How to have Spinner dropdown full width?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have this code of Spinner in XML:

```
<Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    android:dropDownWidth="match_parent"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
```

But the dropdown width is cropped because of the icon shown. How to make it full width like the parent?

[image]

Comment: this answer suggests a workaround if you want to keep the arrow and still have the dropdown menu take up the full width: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47548396/10300673

Comment: Hi @NikosHidalgo I managed to solve it by programmatically, going to post it shortly

Answer (score 2):

I am able to solve it do it programmatically:

```
parentLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 16) {
            parentLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        } else {
            parentLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
        }

        spinnerDropdown.setDropDownWidth(parentLayout.getWidth());
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this. Any idea how the listener affected your desired outcome?

Comment: As in my case, I need the `spinnerDropdown` to be full width of the `parentLayout`, so I only need to set the dropdownWidth to be equal `parentLayout`'s width, thus, need to be done in onGlobalLayout

Comment: match parent wasn't working for me, but his worked thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on randy's solution

Targeted device on and above 21

Reusable extension

```
fun ViewGroup.addViewObserver(function: (View) -> Unit) {
val view = this
view.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
    override fun onGlobalLayout() {
        view.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
        function.invoke(view)
    }
})
```

}

In Activity

```
fromGrade.addViewObserver {
            spnGrade.dropDownWidth = it.width
}
```